# How to access JSON.parsed object in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I did `JSON.parse` and getting output in javascript variable "temp" in format like this

```
{"2222":{"MId":106607,
"Title":"VIDEOCON Semi Automatic Marine 6.8kg",
"Name":"washma01",
}}
```

I tried like

```
alert(temp[0][0]);
alert(temp.2222[0].MId);
```

but not getting output.

How will I access this data in javascript ?

Answer (score 17):

```
alert(temp["2222"].MId);
```

You can't use numeric indexing, because don't have any actual arrays.  You can use dot syntax if the first character of the key is non-numeric.  E.g.:

```
var temp = JSON.parse('{"n2222":{"MId":106607, "Title":"VIDEOCON Semi Automatic Marine 6.8kg", "Name":"washma01", }}');
alert(temp.n2222.MId);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
temp["2222"].MId
```

Typically `temp.bar` and `temp["bar"]` are equivalent JavaScript statements, but in this case one of your property name starts with a number.  When this happens you are forced to use the index (aka bracket) notation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the variable like so temp['2222']['MId'] , That will give you the value of MId. Even though I have shown using the [] method of getting the value , the answers below work as well.

You can run this test below in firebug.

```
var ss = {"2222":{"MId":106607, "Title":"VIDEOCON Semi Automatic Marine 6.8kg", "Name":"washma01"}};
console.log(ss['2222']['MId']);
```

Answer (score 0):

when you have a good json formated object, but you don't know the key (here it look like an id) you can acces like this :

```
var keys = Object.keys(json_obj);
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    console.log(keys[i]);
    console.log(json_obj[keys[i]].MId);
};
```