# Can't access value from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this JSON string:

```
{
    "attachedFiles": [{
        "link": "/site.com/dir?id=12993&SESSION=40af90dd-c1f3-4678-93e5-a4b36f3597b0&SESSIONTICKET=SESS:67bf209be2",
        "fileName": "file1.txt",
        "docDate": "24.02.2014",
        "docTime": "13:54",
        "docId": "12993"
    }],
    "requestId": 48,
    "tasksId": 0,
    "workId": 10558
}
```

I'm converting it like this:

```
var resdata = xhr.responseText; // the string response from the server
var resObj = JSON.parse(resdata);
```

And then I'm trying to access(print the value) `fileName` inside of the `attachedFiles` object by the code below:

```
console.log(resObj.attachedFiles.fileName);
```

It always returns `undefined`. I know that I'm mising something real small here, but I'm not able to spot it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access JSON.parsed object in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570487/how-to-access-json-parsed-object-in-javascript)

Comment: The result is an array so you'd have to specify an index `resObj.attachedFiles[0].fileName`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`attachedFiles` is array. So try access the array content using indexer

```
resObj.attachedFiles[0].fileName // 0th index, 1st Element
```

To access all elements in the array. Thanks to @Cerbus comment

```
for(var i = 0, l = resObj.attachedFiles.length; i < l;i++)
{
   console.log(resObj.attachedFiles[i].fileName);
}
```

Comment: please note that `[0]` accesses the first attached file in the `attachedFiles` array.
If you want to access a variable amount of elements in the array, you're going to have to iterate the array with a `for` loop: `for(var i = 0, l = resObj.attachedFiles.length; i < l; i++){console.log(resObj.attachedFiles[i]);}`

Answer (score 3):

`attachedFiles` is an `array` so use `indexer` it is **zero based index** so first element will be at zero index.

```
console.log(resObj.attachedFiles[0].fileName);
```